# How can I make a butterfly textured with nanostructured structural paint which looks like embroidery or a painted rocky foil texture?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, edges

Picture of reference:

[image: Colorful butterfly painted with structural paint containing tiny aluminum nanoparticles]

I already have the basic shape down:

[image: Basic butterfly shape without texture and details like the jagged edges]

---

I am just having trouble with the textures and details at the edge (i.e connecting the squares to form a smooth edge and little bits that stick out). Do I have to do it manually or is there a procedural way?

Comment: Simon Thommes released a node group called Knittr that can be picked up for free, it is for procedural yarn/fabric texture.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Is the butterfly printed with paint or embroidered? Can't you do the edge smoothing in a paint program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'procedural route' might be via a shader, rather than geometry. This one depends on an 'Offset Grid' group, which divivides a 2D texture space into rectangular cells. It allows changing the relative X and Y scales, and an adjustable offset for each row:

[image]

The group returns UV coordinates per-cell, and 'Cell Idx'.. the position of  (0,0) in each cell. It would typically be used for bricks, and weaves.

It can be used to divide UV space into with square cells, each row offset by half a cell:

[image]

- The whole space is noise-distorted to prevent the weave from being to regular, and produce little fuzzy threads
- A weave-bump is produced from the distance-to-cell-center, which also darkens the color in the cracks
- The effect of threads is left to 'Roughness' alone, but you could add another layer of Bump.
- The image is pixellated by using the cell-center as the lookup into it.

This is really only an example..

[image]

So far, it's looking OK close-up:

[image]

It could, I'm sure, be tweaked to your needs, should this be a way to go for you.

[image]

Comment: A good use of *float curve*